# PHPEXCEL PDF LIBRARIES

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I have a wamp installation. I have installed and used without any problems PhpExcel library to create excel files from some mysql queries.
Now I want to use PhpExcel to create some pdf files.
I have downloaded and installed DomPdf and tcpdf. The folders are in C:\wamp\www
I found that in order to use phpexcel with pdf libraries i have to use this code.

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_TCPDF
$rendererLibrary = 'tcPDF5.9';
$rendererLibraryPath = '/php/libraries/PDF/' . $rendererLibrary;

if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer(
$rendererName,
$rendererLibraryPath
)) {
die(
'NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' .
EOL .
'at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure');
}
```

I have tried to use in the $rendererLibraryPath every possible path but all i get every time is :

NOTICE: Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values
at the top of this script as appropriate for your directory structure.
Also the same Notice comes even when I am trying to use 21pdf.php from phpexcel examples.

Please help. I have spent almost 2 days in this.

Comment: Well, what does the documentation of `PHPEXCEL` say about setting a "pdf renderer"?

Comment: Before instantiating a Writer to generate PDF output, you will need to indicate which Rendering library you are using, and where it is located.
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_MPDF; $rendererLibrary = 'mPDF5.4'; $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../libraries/PDF/' . $rendererLibrary; if (!PHPExcel_Settings::setPdfRenderer( $rendererName, $rendererLibraryPath )) { die( 'Please set the $rendererName and $rendererLibraryPath values' . PHP_EOL . ' as appropriate for your directory structure' ); }

Comment: Hi, I am also having the same problem, there seems to be a problem with the setPdfRenderer, coz when I ran it shows the NOTICE text.  $rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
 $rendererLibrary = 'dompdf/';
 $rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/plugin/dompdf/'.$rendererLibrary;